# MongoDB check that similar named fields exist?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mean-stack

So I can use this to check if field `name` exists in collections `projects`:

```
var filter = {'name':{$exists:true}};
db.getCollection('projects').find(filter);
```

But is there anyway to search for similar fields (nameCap, nameLiterats) for example `name*`

Answer (score 0):

current mongodb version does not allow  to search for nameCap , nameLiterats for the field.

Please find the reference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-element/